# Determining which element referred current html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML page with two buttons. Both of these buttons referring same page, say Test2. While working on Test2(creating new elements etc..) I need to know which button was clicked. Here is an example code:

HTML1:

```
<head>
<title>Test 1</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="Main" id="Main">
<div id="Div1"> 
<button id="Btn1"  onclick="window.location.href='Test2.html';"> this is Button 1 </button>
</div>
<div id="Div2"> 
<button id="Btn2"  onclick="window.location.href='Test2.html';"> this is Button 2 </button>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

HTML2:

```
    <head>
    <title>Test 2</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
if (1==1) { //if something happened
    var aaa=window.document.referrer.source;
    alert(aaa)}
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This code results with "undefined" alert message. How could I get id of button or div that referred to Test2.html?

Comment: There are multiple ways, one of them setting href to Test2.html?id=Div1 and then retrieve that on page2

Comment: Make the link point to `Test2.html?id=Btn1` then you can read `Btn1` in Test2 with this: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the use of `onclick` to just set the new location I would add a query parameter to each URL:

```
<button … onclick=onclick="window.location.href='Test2.html?btn=1';" … >#
```

And then parse the query string in the code in `Test2.html`.